# noiseAlert app isn't working on my phone

Tags: android, audio

I want to do some app that will take level of noise, i try to use this example 
[NoiseAlert](http://code.google.com/p/android-labs/source/browse/trunk/NoiseAlert/src/com/google/android/noisealert/), there are sources and apk. I run that app but there are not any changes in nosemeter. What may it be ? I use LG optimus one 2.3.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only class you need is the [`SoundMeter`](http://code.google.com/p/android-labs/source/browse/trunk/NoiseAlert/src/com/google/android/noisealert/SoundMeter.java) class that records sound. You use `getAmplitude()` to know the current external noise. Get the amplitude every 500 ms. Print this values in LogCat.

Then put on [some music](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=Ee6xkwVucIE#t=32s) at a loud volume and see if the amplitude values jump. If it does not it could be a device specific problem

Comment: I have tried this [example](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/audio-capture.html) in LogCat i can see "SetAudioSource failed"